# Months Between Two dates columns in a table in SQL server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with:

```
DocNum, DocDate, DocDueDate, ItemCode and Quantity
```

Now I need to find the list of months between `Docdate` and `DocDuedate` in this table with the details of all other columns.
For example:

```
DocNum  DocDate   DocDuedate Itemcode Quantity
10001   20180101  20180509   A0001    100
```

I need a result like this:

```
DocNum Monthdetails Itemcode Quantity
10001  20180101     A0001    100
10001  20180201     A0001    100
10001  20180301     A0001    100
10001  20180401     A0001    100
10001  20180501     A0001    100
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: To clarify, you want an output row for each 1st-of-month between 2 dates in an input row?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you'd want a `CROSS APPLY` with a table-valued-function which returns the rows for a given date range.

Comment: Google "calendar table"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CTE Recursive write a calendar

```
;WITH CTE(DocNum,DocDate,DocDuedate,Itemcode,Quantity) AS(
   SELECT DocNum,DocDate,DocDuedate,Itemcode,Quantity
   FROM T
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT DocNum,DATEADD(MONTH,1,DocDate) DocDate, DocDuedate,Itemcode,Quantity
   FROM CTE
   WHERE DATEADD(MONTH,1,DocDate) <= DocDuedate
)

SELECT t.DocNum,
      convert(varchar, t.DocDate, 112) as DocDate,
      t.Itemcode,
      t.Quantity
FROM CTE t
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/790b9/7*

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be like following query without using CTE.

```
select DocNum, Dateadd(month, m.number, docdate) as Monthdetails, Itemcode, Quantity 
from   [TableName] t 
       inner join (
           select distinct number 
            FROM master..[spt_values] 
            where number>=0 and number<1200
           ) m 
               on Dateadd(month, m.number, docdate) between 
                  t.docdate and t.docduedate
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/PXP92462)</kbd>**

**Note:** Above query will work for date difference of 100 years only, if you want more you need to increase the value of number<=1200